# Like UNPIVOT in SQL!

Tags: mysql, aggregate, pivot, mysql-5.7, unpivot

How to change the way that cols orders it self?

If we have a table like this

```
a        b        c
1        xx       xy
2        xy       yx
3        yy       xx
```

Since both of b and c are same type I would like to aggregate them in a one col call E respectively

```
a        E
1        xx
1        xy
2        xy
2        yx
3        yy
3        xx
```

**Is that possible using MYSQL 5.7 ?**

Comment: Use `union all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it with a [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) (you may or may not need the `ORDER BY` part, depending on your use-case):

```
SELECT
    a, b as `E`
FROM
    a
UNION ALL 
SELECT
    a, c as `E`
FROM
    a 
ORDER BY
    a ;
```

You can [check it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/997d71/6/0).

Comment: will union handle complicated joins so?

Comment: These aren't actually joins, but there is no theoretical limit on how many columns you can *unpivot* / *pivot*